# CORS issue with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm using:

- Vue 2.0.3
- vue-router 2.0.1
- vuex 0.8.2
- vue-resource 0.7.0

And after trying to login to my page when using remote API, not the locally run one, I get cors error like following

```
vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1074 OPTIONS 

https://mywebsite/api/auth/login 

(anonymous function) @     vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1074
Promise$1            @     vue-resource.common.js?2f13:681
xhrClient            @     vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1033
Client               @     vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1080
(anonymous function) @     vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1008


XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywebsite/api/auth/login. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed 
access. The response had HTTP status code 415.
```

Now I have API running in Azure, and since it allows me to test my calls from Postman, I am quite sure the CORS headers are set properly on backend.
Not so sure about the Vue and the front.

I have situation like this in config files:

```
export const API_ROOT = 'https://mywebsite/api/'
export const AuthResource = Vue.resource(API_ROOT + 'auth{/action}')
```

than i.e I am calling this action like:

```
login: function (userData) {
    return AuthResource.save({action: 'login'}, userData)
}
```

Finally as I am checking auth in login via token in vuex submodule I have
just a simple header check-up state.

```
var updateAuthHeaders = () => {
    var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth_token"))
    if (token != null){
        Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
    }else{
        Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = null
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true` here, but did not help the case.

Any idea? What am I doing wrong.. I suppose it will not work for other calls also if it doesn't work for login.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a CORS issue (as indicated by the 415 error) and there is nothing wrong with your code of client-end. Could you please provide your key code snippet of your backend?

Comment: you were totally right! There was my issue with API project not allowing access from the JS inside browsers

Comment: @desicne can you tell what was your issue?

Comment: @Darem wasn't a front-end issue. Server setup was not done right at the time.

Answer (score 36):

You face this error when the API url and client url aren't the same. Vue CLI 3 (and in the core of it, Webpack) allows you to proxy your API url to your client url.

Inside `vue.config.js` file add following lines:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // options...
  devServer: {
        proxy: 'https://mywebsite/',
    }
}
```

And then send your ajax calls to `http://localhost/api/`.

You can read the full article here:
[How to deal with CORS error on Vue CLI 3?](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3)

Comment: Thanks! Cool hack! For my case I need to add port when running it in development. 

```module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: "http://localhost/api"
  }
}```

Comment: i am getting the following error
Proxy error: Could not proxy request / from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/.

Comment: What is there are some api  on the localhost  where the vuejs resides, and need to call some api which reside on  another server. In that  case , @Negar  your solution does not works. I have a proejct , which contains larvel api and vuejs.  Vuej consuming larvel api fine but when call to other api is made it give cors error. Your implementation give error method not found.

Comment: I'm using VITE and not VUE-CLI. Any suggesstion in this?

Answer (score 8):

1) Be sure that *server* sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header.

2) `Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true`, `Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` and etc. don't needed in the *client* request.

3) `Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true` should helps if 1 and 2 points already are ok, but vue-resource fails with `status 0`. Also, try to remove (if they exist) `Vue.http.options.credentials = true` and
`Vue.http.options.emulateHTTP = true`.

Answer (score 7):

While you can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your *server* response (in this case IIS) but this is very much advised against.

What's happening here is that your *client* is `http://localhost` and it is trying to access `https://mywebsite/api/` which means they're not from the same *origin*

If you add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` you will be allowing the entire world to hit your API endpoint.

I'd suggest making your access control *server* headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.mysite` and make a vhost for your `localhost` to use `dev.mysite` or similar.

This will allow your "localhost" to access your API without issues.

You could also add `localhost` to a whitelist, but this is also not without its own security implications, and it [doesn't work everywhere](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) anyway.

So, in short, make a vhost for your localhost that's in the same domain as your REST service and your issue should be resolved.

Once you go live you should remove the `*.mysite` part and use as specific a domain as possible on your whitelist.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Greater possibility is that CORS is not enabled on the IIS. This can be enabled by modifying the web.config file in the application root folder in IIS as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Note**: This method will allow anyone to reach the API endpoint and hence shouldn't be adopted on a production environment but only on a development environment.

Answer (score -4):

**Just attach these in the response to your all API's**

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Authorization');

Comment: This is terribly unsafe if it makes it to production

Comment: @darryn.ten can you please guide me with correct way?

Comment: Unsafe solution shouldn't be response to a connection or CORS issue.