# Can vue-resource send POST request directly when cross domain?

Tags: ajax, flask, vue.js

I use vue.js to build a frontend and run it on `http://localhost:8080` with `npm run dev` to develop.

And I use flask to build a backend and run it on `http://localhost:8081`.

**I also set the crossdomain decorator for my route in Flask**:

```
def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator

@app.route("/api", methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin="*")
def test():
    return "hello world"
```

Then I send a `POST` request by `vue-resource` to the backend:

```
this.$http.post("http://localhost:8081/api", "somedata").then({}, {})
```

No surprisingly, the browser send an `OPTIONS` request.

So my questions are:

1. Now that the server side has allow crossdomain, can I send `POST` request directly by `vue-resource`?
2. If not, must I use CORS from flask_cors?
3. Is there any way that I can run frontend and backend both on `8080` port, which can prevents from crossdomain problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't seen all your front-end code, but I do wonder if you've set the Vue.http.headers?

you can, on the front end, set your common headers like this:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = value;
```

More information here:
[CORS issue with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863417/cors-issue-with-vue-js)

EDIT: Did this solve your question?