# Vue Resource (GET) not sending headers

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I know about Axios, but I am trying to do this with Vue Resource.
Everything is working fine but is not sending the headers.

No matter what I do, it won't send the headers.

However, when I execute the query and **resend it** with Firefox console (after adding the auth header) it does work.

But when executing directly from Vue it does not send the header. 
When I try to do the exact same thing in Postman, it does work :)

**Question:** Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
            this.$http.get('https://myapi.com/v1/whatever/option', {
                params: {

                },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer Cd34dfhnc4jn-39q84cq9-pwncpqw349fn83q47903qpnf98nghwehj5UiDXyC:$2y$1gerg34cqw4yas4yqOHAyLk4wy2OkDvxH6HOs.CgocO2TE9Te'
                }
            }).then(response => {

                //console.log(response);

            }, response => {

                console.log('error:');
                console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));
                console.log(response);

            })
```

P.S. I just tried Axios, and the same problem here... when I check my request, my added headers are NOT there!?

[Download my FF Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqp70.jpg)

In my Vue file I have a @click event:

```
this.$http.get('https://boinu.nl/v1/synonyms/autos', {
                // params: {
                //
                // },
                // headers: {
                //  'Authorization' : 'Bearer CdcmXCj0pdaM7UH6zpWVRSyncWJHhShHPKzvj4wWxNaxIn54LGQMaVU7ihUiDXyC:$2y$10$26IZut5mWqtECbhVIFnSqOHAyLk4wy2OkDvxH6HOs.CgocO2TE9Te'
                // }
            }).then(response => {

                //console.log(response);

            }, response => {

                console.log('error:');
                console.log(response);

            })
```

and in my main.js I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Why are you doing `.then(response => { //Content }` **`,`** `response`

Comment: Why not? :P I took it from a VueJS tutorial ;) it works fine except for not being able to send headers along with the request :(

Comment: @NoobieSatan He's using this method format `this.$http.get('/someUrl', [config]).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Comment: I am following a tutorial from Maximilian from Udemy. Good tutorial, but yeah... this part ain't working haha.

Comment: @AngelovanCleef what version of vue-resource are you using?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte It's version 1.5.1 I recon? downloaded it a couple of hours from this link: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: @AngelovanCleef Could not find anything similar to your problem, but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45081861/7395911) can help.

Comment: Create a GitHub repo and let me examine your code

Comment: Ill put it on git tomorrow. Thanks everyone for your replies so far!

Comment: I updated my main post with the code...