# Need a way to enable CORS in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to vueJS and version using is 2.0. I need to fetch some JSON data from url. Using javacsript fetch methods to get the data from URL. below is my code,

```
function getValue() {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "GET",
                header: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "GET"}
            };
              fetch("http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA", requestOptions)
                .then(
                    (response) => {
                        console.log(response.json());
                    }
                );
        }

        getValue();
```

I am getting CORS issue like,

```
Access to fetch at 'http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**I tried all the possibilities which available in stack-overflow. But no luck.** 
Any help would be much appreciated. 
JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/m45hsekf/

Comment: CORS should be enabled at server level like node or java application.

Answer (score 0):

CORS should be enabled at server level like node or java application.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "test-client.com" or use "*"`(not recommended). Then allow this value at the server

Get is your http method not the origin value

To enable in node use this line

```
res. header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // again * is not a best practice. Please accept this as answer too
```

Refer to the url below for more info
https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node

Comment: ok. i am new to this concept. please let me know how to enable in node. Thanks

Comment: I have update my answer and pleae accept it as answer if it helps

Comment: Tried this and not working :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863417/cors-issue-with-vue-js/45081861 - this should help

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set the mode to `no-cors` like the error suggests to you?

> set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS
>   disabled.

I have tested it and it works:

```
const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors"
};
```

So the request looks like this:

```
fetch("http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA", {
  mode: "no-cors"
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Tried this, and getting error like `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in `response.json()`. Dont know whats the reason

Comment: then check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696999/fetch-unexpected-end-of-input

Answer (score 0):

when i have problems while i develop, i use crhome extension called CORS UNBLOCK, then i can test my api, and when i deploy to final server, always is in the same domain then i havent cors ploblem